# How to verify embedded document before saving?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I've got a basic spring rest api system based on Spring and mongdb.
 two simple models which represent two collections  : User and Book

With one to many relationship: one user can have multiple books

I would like to verify on creating/updating a user , that the related books exist on books collection. What should be the best practice to do that? Is there a solution in spring for this?

I thought of getting books as an array of id's and validate them in the controller , and then if the validation is correct, get them from books collections and save them
and then i think , Users models should have array of ids, instead of books object
Or maybe there is better way?

User model:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private List<Book> books;

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }



    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Users controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public void createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Optional<User> getUserById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public void updateUser(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody User user) {
        user.setId(id);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should use @DBRef or @Reference for the books attribute.
About the best practice for verifying the books is using mongo event listener

```
@Component
public class BeforeSaveListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<User> {
  // you can inject the books repository
  @Override
  public void onBeforeSave(BeforeSaveEvent<User> event) {
   // verify the books and throw exception if not valid
  }
}
```